# Function used to filter in AngularJS 1.7 doesn't have "this" context

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I am in the process of swapping out some controllers to components.  I have a controller that has a custom filter function:

```
function MyController($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.customFilter = function(item) {
     $filter('filter')([item], $scope.search);
  }
}
```

in my template:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search">
<div ng-repeat="item in (filtered = (items | filter:customFilter))" >
```

This works great when I have access to $scope.  My filter function is much more complex, but a one off.  I don't really need to define it as a true filter for the app as its not used anywhere else.  Hence just a custom function in the controller itself.

However I am moving my controller over to component and don't have access to $scope.

```
class MyComponent {
  constructor($filter) {
    this.$filter = $filter;
    this.search = '';
  }
  customFilter(item) {
     this.$filter('filter')([item], this.search);
  }
  onCustomClick() {
    // if this is called from ng-click
    // I can access 'this' here, why not in filter
  }  
}
```

Template:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.search">
<div ng-repeat="item in ($ctrl.filtered = (items | filter:$ctrl.customFilter))">
```

The customFilter function is called as before, however it has no context bound.  The 'this' variable is undefined.  Am I doing something wrong, or should I be able to access the context of my component in the filter function?

If I call a function in ng-click the 'this' context is bound correctly, is this a limitation of calling a function of the component to filter?

Comment: is your search variable defined in your component/controller or it is created only in html?

Comment: @FarukT yes, I updated the question.  However it doesn't matter what is defined as the 'this' scope/context is undefined when called into the filter function.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think when filter calls your function it creates own context and for this reason you have a this of undefined.

A fast and alternative solution can be this sample, you can also pass parameters to filter function you defined and it will return an anonymous function

```
class MyComponent {
    constructor() {
      this.search = '';
    }
    customFilter(searchText) {
        return function (item) {
            $filter('filter')([item], searchText);
        }
    }
    onCustomClick() {
      // if this is called from ng-click
      // I can access 'this' here, why not in filter
    }  
  }
```

Template:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.search">
<div ng-repeat="item in ($ctrl.filtered = (items | filter:$ctrl.customFilter($ctrl.search)))">
```